# what kind of support or performance can i expect from ubuntu on a chromebook?

Tags: chromebook

has anyone installed a ubuntu on a chromebook (acer or samsung ) yet?  What has been the experience so far?  What kind of hardware support is there?  Are you getting expected performance?

Comment: There is an Xubuntu-based spin called GalliumOS for the x86 platform, They maintain a [hardware compatibility in their wiki list](https://wiki.galliumos.org/Hardware_Compatibility). Regarding performance you should be looking for comparisons of the individual processors which can also be found in other computing devices and take into account that newer models usually don't have SSDs but typically eMMC storage. You can find similar hardware in compute sticks these days which can run Windows 10, how well a OS runs is very subjective without any specific criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've installed it and have almost no problems, almost because sometimes while I'm writing the input does not immediately appears on the monitor, it takes a couple of seconds.

Generally speaking I've found no problems at all and I'm happy with it, even if it took a bit more than others to install ubuntu on the chromebook.

The touchpad works okay (it's some users main concern), I'm having some problems to set up the 3g connection, which is way I'm going to post about it right now. :P

I've blogged my experience here: http://lazywithclass.posterous.com

Answer (score 4):

Here is the minimum system requirements for a ubuntu mahcine:

```
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements
```

Here is a guide to install Ubuntu 11.04 onto a ChromeBook:

```
http://chromeos-cr48.blogspot.com/2011/04/ubuntu-1104-for-cr-48-is-ready.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Since most chromebooks are based on netbook specs, you can expect performance which would be on a par with netbook computers. In other words you should be able to run most tools without a hitch. Ive seen decent speed in even worse spec computers so you should be OK